# how to get 1 year old alert details from dataware house in scom using powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, scom

how to get  1 year old alert details in scom using powershell?

i have tried:

get-alert | Where-Object { $_.TicketId -ilike "IR-*"}

but getting only 1 week old alerts. please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 1 week old alerts because it only store 1 week alert by default. You have to change the database grooming setting.